# Allegro 5 and FreeBASIC

Tags: windows, dll, allegro5, freebasic

I cannot find a way to make **Allegro5** work with **FreeBasic** on Windows.
I downloaded and installed FreeBASIC-1.05.0-win32.exe.
I downloaded Allegro binaries allegro-5.0.10-mingw-4.7.0.
The version of fbc installed is the standalone one.
I created allegrolibs folder and copied these libraries from the Allegro distribution to allegrolibs:

```
  liballegro_5.0.10-md.a  
  liballegro_font-5.0.10-md.a  
  liballegro_ttf-5.0.10-md.a
```

I added the necessary allegro dlls from the Allegro distribution to examples/graphics/allegro:

```
  allegro_font-5.0.10-md.dll  
  allegro_ttf-5.0.10-md.dll  
  allegro-5.0.10-md.dll
```

I run fbc from the command line, trying to compile hello.bas from examples/graphics/allegro5:

```
 fbc -s gui -p allegrolibs examples/graphics/allegro5/hello.bas
```

The program compiled just fine.
However, at runtime hello.exe shows me this error:

```
  The program can't start because libgcc_s_dw2_1.dll is missing from your computer.
```

Copy libgcc_s_dw2_1.dll from FreeBASIC\bin\win32 to the folder where hello.exe resides, then run:

```
  The program can't start because libstdc++-6.dll is missing from your computer.
```

Add libstdc++-6.dll from a ming4.7.0 binary distribution then run:

```
  The program can't start because libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll is missing from your computer.
```

Add libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll from ming4.7.0 binary distribution then run:

```
  The program can't start because libwinpthread-1.dll is missing from your computer.
```

Add libwinpthread-1.dll from ming4.7.0 binary distribution then run:

```
  The procedure entry point __gxx_personality_v0 could not be located
  in the dynamic link library libstd++-6.dll.
```

At this point I'm stuck. What is it that I'm doing wrong? Anybody who tried the same and was able to solved it is willing to help with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

allegro-5.0.10-mingw-4.7.0 binary for Windows was compiled with mingw-4.7.0 compiler.
freeBASIC was compiled with a mingw-w64 compiler.
But as far as dynamic linking, they can work together.
The binary package for Windows allegro-5.0.10-mingw-4.7.0 contains among many other things two files:

```
allegro-5.0.10-monolith-mt.dll
liballegro-5.0.10-monolith-mt.a
```

Either of them can be used to link Allegro 5 library to the exe:
Copy allegro-5.0.10-monolith-mt.dll or liballegro-5.0.10-monolith-mt.a in allegrolib folder.
Modify allegro.bi, allegro_font.bi, allegro_ttf.bi replacing line 35 with:

```
#inclib "allegro-5.0.10-monolith-mt"
```

Run from the console:

```
fbc -s gui -p allegrolib examples/graphics/allegro5/hello.bas
```

allegro-5.0.10-monolith-mt.dll needs to be placed in the same folder with hello.exe.